# Replace xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this code:

```
<p>2&ensp;If the patient is unknown to the service a comprehensive assessment must be carried out prior to undertaking the procedure. (Reference <xref target="http://www.google.com" style="unformatted"/>)</p>
```

I want this xml to be like this:

```
<p><b>2</b>If the patient is unknown to the service a comprehensive assessment must be carried out prior to undertaking the procedure. (Reference <xref target="http://www.google.com" style="unformatted"/>)</p>
```

By using XSL 1.0
I have tried many ways to replace string but the node (xref) is removed!!

Comment: Post the way(s) you have tried so that they can be edited/reviewed and fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written a template with `match="p"` which does the string replacement then change that to have `match="p/text()"` (or `match="p//text()"` if you need the replacement in descendants too) and then make sure you have the identity transformation template in place:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It is not clear to me which substring exactly you want to replace or wrap with a `b` element, an example of the approach suggested above is at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVC, it does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template name="wrap">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="search"/>
    <xsl:param name="wrap-name"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($string, $search))">
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search)"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$wrap-name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$search"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="wrap-name" select="$wrap-name"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
        <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'2&#8194;'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="wrap-name" select="'b'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```